# How can I sort numbers from high to low followed by letters in PHP?

Tags: php, list, sorting

Basically I need to sort a list that can contain either years or words, and I would like to have it put the most recent years at the top, and any words below all of the years.

So if the list contains 2012,2013,2014,apple,banana,couch; I would like it to be sorted as this :

2014,
2013,
2012,
apple,
banana,
couch

How could this be done?

Comment: See `min` and `max` => http://php.net/manual/en/ref.math.php as an additional PHP method.

Comment: Your list is split sorted.  The numbers are descending and the words are ascending.

Comment: You need to loop thru the list and split all the entries into two new lists, one containing only numbers and the other containing only letters. Then sort each new list in whatever direction you want. Then put the two lists back together by just adding one to the end of the other one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of built-in php sorting functions, but they won't cover *all* the weird edge cases.  For example, you could *almost* use something simple like `natsort()` if you weren't sorting in different directions.  With most kinds of custom sorts like the one you want (by numbers descending, then words ascending) you may be best off writing your own simple sort comparison function!

So check out `usort()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php for that.
Essentially, you pass it the array and a function that you write that returns 1, 0, or -1 depending on the desired comparison of two sort elements, and you'll get back out a sorted version of the array.

Alternatively, you may want to sort the data coming out of the database first, as that's generally much faster.